# Interfaz gráfica (cambiar ventanas)

Tags: java, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy trabajando en una interfaz gráfica pues es una tarea, lo que quiero hacer es que apretar un botón me cambie del `JFrame` a `JDialog` pero sin abrirlo en forma de pestaña, es decir, que la ventana que contiene los botones de opción se "borre" para dar paso a nueva interfaz.

Ojo: La foto es evidencia, no quiero que haga eso.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]